# Why does REGEX_REPLACE return the whole string of non-matches?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySQL 8 and have a Regex that needs to return a Regex group from a table column of string data.

[DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WAdXxGmwcdCDWH7Bbk85G/2)

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE `table_name`(
    id_column VARCHAR(300)
);
INSERT INTO `table_name` VALUES
('47099085T'),
('D73654109H'),
('8.30781719e-05'),
('0113:11:19%2000:54:17.042828927Z');
```

SQL:

```
 SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(id_column,
        '[^\\.0-9]([0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])', '$1') as id_output
 FROM `table_name`
```

Regex [expected output here](https://regex101.com/r/2dD0fz/1) (regex101.com)

The Regex contains a group, whose REGEX replace is used to return to the SELECT.

```
> "47099085T"                         // matches and returns value in quotes.
> D"73654109H"                        // matches and returns value in quotes.
> 8.30781719e-05                      // unmatched
> 0113:11:19%2000:54:17.042828927Z    // unmatched
```

The [MySQL manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) states:

> ```
>   REGEXP_REPLACE(expr, pat, repl[, pos[, occurrence[, match_type]]])
> ```
>
> Replaces occurrences in the string expr that match the regular expression specified by the pattern pat with the replacement string repl, and returns the resulting string. **If expr, pat, or repl is NULL, the return value is NULL**.

#### Expected outcome:

| id_output |
| --- |
| 47099085T |
| 73654109H |

#### Actual outcome:

| id_output |
| --- |
| 47099085T |
| 73654109H |
| 8.30781719e-05 |
| 0113:11:19%2000:54:17.042828927Z |

So for the two rows that do not match the sub group, I am expecting the return on the REGEX_REPLACE to be NULL, because there isn't any match. But it instead returns the whole column's data.

#### Why?

How can I edit the REGEXP to only return matching outcomes?

Comment: Literal dot char does not need in quoting in "not in" list. https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WAdXxGmwcdCDWH7Bbk85G/4

Comment: If the pattern doesn't match, nothing is replaced. If nothing is replaced, the output is the same as the input. Simple.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT id_column,
       REGEXP_REPLACE(id_column, '([^\\d.])(\\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])', '$2') 
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE id_column REGEXP '(^|[^\\d.])(\\d{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])'
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WAdXxGmwcdCDWH7Bbk85G/4

Comment: Ahh that's brilliant, that works as intended. Thank you!

Comment: Great, You corrected the expression

Comment: Don't just post code. Explain what you did, so you actually answer the question.

Answer (score 4):

The [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function pretty much does the same thing

Basically, both [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) would simply return the original string if there was nothing to replace in the original string.

Just imagine your query written as an UPDATE

```
UPDATE table_name SET id_column =
REGEXP_REPLACE(id_column,'[^\\.0-9]([0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])', '$1') ;
```

That would be quite destructive if you want [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) to return nothing. In light of this, it is a very good thing that both [REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) and [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) would return the original string.

## SUGGESTION : Use a WHERE Clause

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(id_column, 
'[^\\.0-9]([0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])', '$1')
as id_output FROM `table_name` WHERE id_column <>
REGEXP_REPLACE(id_column, 
'[^\\.0-9]([0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke])', '$1');
```

The db-fiddle Query is even better WHERE cluase

```
SELECT id_column
FROM `table_name` 
WHERE id_column REGEXP
'[^\\.0-9][0-9]{8}[TRWAGMYFPDXBNJZSQVHLCKEtrwagmyfpdxbnjzsqvhlcke]'l
```

## What about the MySQL Documentation ???

Your citation of the MySQL Documentation points to the parameters of [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) being NULL. It makes no mention of the return value of [REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace).

## UPDATE 2023-01-20 10:50 EST

[REGEXP_REPLACE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-replace) should not return the same value in any instance. The only thing I can think of is if you are running an older version of MySQL 8.0. There is a character set bug mentioned on that documentation page:

> Prior to MySQL 8.0.17, the result returned by this function used the UTF-16 character set; in MySQL 8.0.17 and later, the character set and collation of the expression searched for matches is used. (Bug #94203, Bug #29308212)

You might need to experiment with [REGEXP_LIKE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html#function_regexp-like) in the WHERE clause and see (I am not a fan of REGEXP stuff).

Comment: I tried the WHERE clause but the problem is some times the column value is an exact match for the Regex group

Comment: Thanks for the update; my query comes from [the DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5WAdXxGmwcdCDWH7Bbk85G/3), rather than usage on my own servers -- the DB fiddle only says it uses MySQL 8.0 but doesn't specify exact versioning.

Comment: I updated the db-fiddle with some hash of return values. Please have a look